# Application.ScreenUpdating = true does not update screen

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excelsheet where I do some dataloading. While this, I turn of Screen Updating with:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

After I turn it on with:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

But the problem is, that the screen is still be freezed. This is only occuring on some customer-machines and sudden in the last few days.

When I remove the two ScreenUpdating-Lines, all is working ok.

Does someone know this phenomenon and knows a solution?

Comment: I just started having this exact same problem, very strange something this basic has worked for so long and now has a major problem.

Comment: @CFRBill can you explain what you have tried out so far?

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that the problem occurs on 32bit excels with compilation number "2206 16.0.15330.20144". At least people with this problem have this Excel version.

On my 64bit and "2206 16.0.15330.20216" version, everything is running smoothly.

A potential fix would be to force update Excel, or change to the 64bit version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the title should be "unable to re-enable ScreenUpdating"

Good idea to pin point version info however, two of my computers are running the following version but only one has the issue.

- 32-bit version.
- Product Version 206 16.0.15330.20230

As suggested this reply is where other threads are being cited in order to support our statements.  Apparently MS thinks it is a coding issue as the thread found on a Microsoft.com domain says to come to Stack Overflow.

From Stack Overflow's viewpoint, I think the solution is to comment out all "Application.ScreenUpdating = True" statements until Microsoft provides a fix.

The first thread confirms the testing done as mentioned in my previous post.

Jul 11 2022 01:54 PM
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/screen-updating-set-to-true-but-screen-does-not-update/m-p/3570457

This one is totally unhelpful:
Posted late July 11
https://www.qandeelacademy.com/questions/application-screenupdating-true-does-not-update-screen

In this thread Microsoft says to come to Stack Overflow for help.
Opened July 3, 2022
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/applicationscreenupdating-true-doesnt-work/8df869d5-df4d-4a08-9abf-674bc4768191

Answer (score 0):

BennoDual,

What I have tried was restarting the computer.  The simplest fix, so far, is to comment out all "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" statements. Leaving the "= True" statements alone.

I'm glad it is not "just me" and, since this now a known issue, my solution is to wait, and test each day for the fix.  For me this issue arose around 3:30 PM on Sunday July 10.  It was working the night before and I think, even Sunday morning.

Here was my testing, after determining the issue.

After creating a new Excel workbook, cell C3 was selected, the following code was executed, and then Sheet1 was reviewed.

Double Clicked A1 and entered "aaa".
Result: A1 appeared empty. Name Box showed cell A1 selected. Formula Bar showed "aaa".  C3 as still outlined.

Scrolled down quite a ways and Double clicked what appeared to be A1 and entered "bbb".
Result:  The cell appeared empty.  Name Box showed A137.  Formula Bar showed "bbb".

I could then use Ctrl+UpArrow and Ctrl+DownArrow which jumped between A1 and A137.  Both still appeared empty but the Formula Bar proved otherwise.

To effectively simulate "Application.ScreenUpdating = True" requires shutting down all currently open Excel Workbooks.  Not just the one where the "= False" was executed.

```
Sub Testing()
   Dim booValue As Boolean

   booValue = Application.ScreenUpdating
   Debug.Print booValue    'Result is True

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   booValue = Application.ScreenUpdating
   Debug.Print booValue    'Result is False

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   booValue = Application.ScreenUpdating
   Debug.Print booValue    'Result is True
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem earlier. I re-installed Microsoft Office. Then, rebooted and it works. I just downloaded the MS office from their portal. Have it re-installed again.

My Excel version is 2305 BNuild 16501.20196.

Comment: Could you please fix the end of your post (everything starting with "Click to run")? There seems to be something missing, or there are punctuation mistakes. Also, please delete the name at the end.